# How to optimize multiple value query from database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel and using simple command to query from database.
I am trying to get multiple value from database with same id.

```
$id = 'P01';
//Get value from database
$fruitname = DB::table('fruits')->where('id', $id)->value('fruitname');
$fruitcolour = DB::table('fruits')->where('id', $id)->value('fruitcolour');
$fruitshape = DB::table('fruits')->where('id', $id)->value('fruitshape');
$updatedat = DB::table('fruits')->where('id', $id)->value('updated_at');

$data = array(
        'fruitname' => $fruitname,
        'fruitcolour' => $fruitcolour,
        'fruitshape' => $fruitshape,
        'updated_at' => $updatedat   
        );
```

As result, `$data` can store the value.
But i found out that it takes time to complete the process.
Is there any ways i can optimize the process?

Comment: just get `fruitname`, `fruitcolour`, `fruitshape`, `updated_at` on one select, makes no sense getting them in each separate calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're making it more hard than it is, but you can just simply use eloquent in this case:

Provided you already have created the necessary model and adding it in your controller:

```
use App\Fruits;
```

Just simply use it in the `find` method:

```
public function someMethodName()
{
    $id = 'P01';
    $fruit = Fruits::find($id);

    echo $fruit->fruitname; // and others
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin, i should explore more on eloquent.

Comment: @Malca you can achieve same result on both approach (either eloquent or query builder), it's just there's multiple database calls on your current code

Comment: If you only need to query sometimes for some fruits a model is a little bit oversized. And QueryBuilder can have better performance in large and heavy used applications.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fruit = DB::table('fruits')->where('id', $id)->first();

$data = array(
        'fruitname' => $fruit->fruitname,
        'fruitcolour' => $fruit->fruitcolour,
        'fruitshape' => $fruit->fruitshape,
        'updated_at' => $fruit->updatedat   
);
```

Or if you have a view,  you could just do

```
$fruit = DB::table('fruits')->where('id', $id)->first();
return view('yourview', compact('fruit'));
```

And in the view, you can access each of the values like so:

```
{{ $fruit->fruitname }} 
{{ $fruit->fruitcolor }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller add function

```
public function function_name(Fruit $fruit)
{
 return view('your_view_name', compact('fruit'));
}
```

In web file set your route as

```
Route::get('/fruit/{fruit}','YourControllername@methodName')->name('show');
```

At the time of setting route
`<a href="{{route('show', ['fruit' => $id])}}">Show</a>`

in View file get data as

```
{{ $fruit->fruitname }} 
{{ $fruit->fruitcolor }}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it with a single query with QueryBuilder since QueryBuilder can have better performance than Eloquent:

```
DB::table('fruits')->where('id', $id)
    ->select(['fruitname', 'fruitcolour', 'fruitshape', 'updated_at'])
    ->first();
```

This returns a associative array with the selected column names.